# How to change nav bar multiple color when scrolling jquery

Tags: jquery, colors, navbar

How to change nav bar multiple color when scrolling jquery

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 54) {
        $("#black").css("background" , "blue");
      }


      else{
          $("#black").css("background" , "white");      
      }
  })
})
      </script>
```

i want to when user scrool 400px color change to green 
i try following but not work

```
else if (scroll > 200) {
        $("#black").css("background" , "green");
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript the evaluation of `if` statements ends as soon as one of them hits. This means that once you scroll past `54px`, then the background will be changed to `blue` and no other conditions, regardless if they may be true or not, will be checked.

Therefore you need to reverse the logic so you put the last case first. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 200) {
      $("#black").css("background-color", "green");
    } else if (scroll > 54) {
      $("#black").css("background-color", "blue");
    } else {
      $("#black").css("background-color", "white");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
#black { 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="black"></div>
```